# How do I join two lines in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to get Information about our VMs in Hyper-V via PowerShell.

This is what I got so far:

```
$Path = 'c:/VM.csv'
"Name,CPUs,Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher,RAM Maximum (in MB),RAM Minimum (in MB), Size" > $Path
$line1 = Get-VM | %{($_.Name, $_.ProcessorCount, $_.DynamicMemoryEnabled, ($_.MemoryMaximum/1MB), ($_.MemoryMinimum/1MB)) -join ","} 
$line2 = Get-VM –VMName * | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | %{$_.FileSize/1GB -join ","} 
$out = $line1+","+ $line2
Write-Output  $out | Out-File $Path -Append 
Import-Csv -Path $Path | Out-GridView
```

The Problem is that the second object (`$line2`) should be in the same column as `$line1`. As you can see, currently the information about the size of the VMs (`$line2`) is written in rows under the output of `$line1`. Also the order is wrong.

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not simply use `export-csv`?

Comment: You threading the lines as strings but apparently expect a list as the end result. Try to replace the last 3 lines to just: `@($line1) + $line2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you messed it up a little,

`Export-CSV` will do the job without the need to manually define the csv structure.

Anyway, regarding your code I think you can improve it a little, (I don't have hyper-v to test this, but I think it should work)

What I've done is create a results array to hold the final data, then using foreach loop i'm iterating the `Get-VM` Results and creating a row for each VM, at the end of each iteration I'm adding the row to the final results array, so:

```
$Results = @()
foreach ($VM in (Get-VM))
{
    $Row = "" | Select Name,CPUs,'Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher','RAM Maximum (inMB)','RAM Minimum (in MB)',Size
    $Row.Name = $VM.Name
    $Row.CPUs = $VM.ProcessorCount
    $Row.'Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher' = $VM.DynamicMemoryEnabled
    $Row.'RAM Maximum (inMB)' = $VM.MemoryMaximum/1MB
    $Row.'RAM Minimum (in MB)' = $VM.MemoryMinimum/1MB
    $Total=0; ($VM.VMId | Get-VHD | %{$Total += ($_.FileSize/1GB)})
    $Row.Size = [math]::Round($Total)
    $Results += $Row
}

$Results | Export-Csv c:\vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks!
Only one Problem remains: If one VM has two or more VHDx attached, the script creates the output `System.Object[]` probably because it has now two values for both VHDx and can not display this in one Row. 
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: try `($VM.VMId | Get-VHD | %{$_.FileSize/1GB}) -join ','`

Comment: Thanks! Any possibility to use `[math]::Round` for `FileSize` before joining the values?

Comment: `($VM.VMId | Get-VHD | %{[math]::Round($_.FileSize/1GB)}) -join ',' `

Comment: The last one: Is it possible to add all values in `$Row.Size` for each VM and the round the results. Thanks in advance!

Comment: updated the answer, your next wish should be in a new question, good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the proper way to build an object list, instead you should do something like this:

```
Get-VM | Select Name, 
    @{Name = "CPUs"; Expression = {$_.ProcessorCount},
    @{Name = "Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher"; Expression = {$_.DynamicMemoryEnabled},
    @{Name = "RAM Maximum (in MB)"; Expression = {$_.MemoryMaximum/1MB},
    @{Name = "RAM Minimum (in MB)"; Expression = {$_.MemoryMinimum/1MB},
    @{Name = "Size"; Expression = {$_.VMId | Get-VHD | %{$_.FileSize/1GB -join ","}} | 
Export-Csv c:\vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Where is the CSV part? The user is more bothered to get that in CSV.

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta, Once you have a proper object list you can pipe it to wherever you want with it. Nevertheless, I have added `Export-Csv ...` but you can also send it to a `Out-GridView`

Comment: Yes I know that. But where in that answer you have mentioned that ? Please edit and put the context. Otherwise this answer remains vague cause the AVshalom had already presented in a proper way.